# Hot to use reduce to convert a array of objects to a single object

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to work with reduce or map, but i'm a noob some times.

i'm trying to use this function to return a single array from the objects.

```
var obj = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];
    var result = obj.reduce((obj, item) => [item.key] = item.value);
    console.log(result);
```

but i'm always getting :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)'
>   of undefined

I searched a lot, but the examples didn't help me... i think that's something simple, but after 1 hour, i'm nothing getting .

What i want..

```
[{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}] to {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use reduce:

```
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

var result = arr.reduce((obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, item), {});
```

Check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) when in doubt.

Comment: that's what i'm searching for... reduce and put the things on the way. Thanks !! I'm tryng to lear how to write less, do more.

Comment: I definitely recommend @nina-scholz object assign + spread syntax if you have a build process with transpiling.
If your code is going straight to the browser then use her ES5 solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...obj));
```

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

console.log(obj.reduce((r, o) => Object.assign(r, o), {}));
```

Without `Object.assign`

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

console.log(obj.reduce((r, o) => (Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = v), r), {}));
```

ES5

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

console.log(obj.reduce(function (r, o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        r[k] = o[k];
    });
    return r;
}, {}));
```

Comment: did work perfectly. But that's a way to do this using reduce? thanks !!!

Comment: Note spread syntax might not work in IE (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: @NinaScholz Right, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in the following way using reduce

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];
    var result = obj.reduce((obj, item) =>  {
    Object.assign(obj, item)
    return obj;
    }, {});
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ohh thanks, now I understand how the reduce really do the things.. it iterate trough the itens and u have to use it.